# height autoflow autofill into out div

Tags: css, css-float

I have a fiddle(http://jsfiddle.net/pwnagecss/LnNYv/) and need help in making it so the classes sideBar, and rightContentWrapper autofill to the height.

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sideBar">

    </div>
    <div class="rightContentWrapper">
        <div class="rightContent">

    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
    width: 960px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
    padding: 0;
    background-color:black;
}
.wrapper:after{
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    content: "0020";
}
.sideBar {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    background-color:blue;
    min-height: inherit;
    height: 100%;
}
.rightContentWrapper {
    float: left;
    width: 760px;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: inherit;
}
.rightContent {
margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: red;
    min-height: inherit;
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used to **Display** `table-cell`

Define your **left** and **right** section `display table-cell` properties

**as like this**

```
.rightContentWrapper ,.sideBar{
    display:table-cell;}
.rightContent{height:100%;}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LnNYv/2/)**

Comment: Ended up going with this one as it worked perfectly with what I was trying to accomplish and there were other advanced elements inside the divs which seemed to work best with this answer

Answer (score 1):

You can try the CSS3 flexbox module, like this:

```
html,body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}
.sideBar {
  width: 220px;
  background: green;
}
.rightContentWrapper {
   background: orange;
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
}
```

Please view the [demo](http://codepen.io/airen/pen/Awflz).

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful as it taught me something new ;D

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not working is because both `.sidebar` and `.rightContent` are set to `min-height:inherit`

In order for `min-height:inherit` to work you will need to define a height for your wrapper element, not `100%` but and actual value ie `700px`.

Also your `.rightContent` will inherit from the `.rightContentWrapper` first, which has no min-height declaration. And will therefor not pass anything on to your `.rightContent`

In order for this to work, either set a fixed minHeight on your wrapper and rightContentWrapper. Or use javascript or jquery to set the height dynamically based on whatever criteria (viewport height maybe)?

Answer (score 0):

I saw you didn't tag jquery, but in case you want it for cross-browser, here is the jquery way.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/LnNYv/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.wrapper').each(function(){
        var max_height = $(this).height();
        $(this).children('.sideBar').css('height',max_height);
        $(this).find('.rightContent').css('height',max_height);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this would work on page load, we're using ajax to load in partial templates which would make the height dynamically change and would probably need a watcher on this

Comment: You can create a function with this script, and call this function again after your ajax load?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, turns out there was a lot of ajaxness going on which made it difficult to get the exact height of the wrapper as usually there were up to 5 calls made before the height was done changing